# How to update my wine version on Fedora 24

Tags: linux, fedora, adobe-photoshop, wine

Good day to you first,

So something to tell you first. I am making migration from Windows to Linux because i love it, but a lot of programs still that are just so damn good on Windows keeps me there.

So i guess i need the latest stable version of Wine to install Photoshop on Fedora

I have Wine 2.0, i want to update it because i don't know do i need the latest version to be able to do that(running PS). Pls tell me if 2.0 is fairly good enough.

Also one other thing to explain.

Recently i red an article for Photoshop on Linux, but it is nowhere said how to get Photoshop. Because it is expensive software and i can't afford to but it right now, will Wine do the trick with trial version ?

Comment: Your time will be better spent monkeying with GIMP than trying to install and run a trial version of any Windows software on Linux. If you really must use PhotoShop, try running it in a VM on Linux if possible. This will be much more reliable than using Wine.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have a licence for Adobe Photoshop, you can consider free software like **Krita** if you use it to draw, or **GIMP** if you use it for image manipulation.

If you really want to use Adobe Photoshop on Fedora, you can try to use https://www.playonlinux.com/ which provides packages to ease Wine configuration: it will download the right version of Wine for a given supported software, and the trial version will work the same as the paid version.